# Visual Studio Code launch.json runtimeArgs with double quotes in the argument

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I'm running Visual Studio Code with the 'Debugger for Chrome' extension to debug some javascript. However, I want to run an out of process pepper plugin while debugging.

Outside of Visual Studio Code we do this by passing the following command line flags to chrome.exe (among others):

```
--register-pepper-plugins="path_to_plugin";mime_type
```

Note: **requires double quotes**

To pass command line arguments to Chrome via Visual Studio Code I set up a launch.json with the following addition:

```
"runtimeArgs" : ["--register-pepper-plugins=\"path_to_plugin\";mime_type"]
```

I can see using ProcessExplorer that my runtimeArgs are being passed to Chrome, but with the escape character \ intact, so what chrome actually receives is:

```
--register-pepper-plugins=\"path_to_plugin\";mime_type
```

rather than

```
--register-pepper-plugins="path_to_plugin";mime_type
```

If I remove the escape character, I only get

```
--register_pepper_plugins=
```

because the second double quote matches the first.

Am I doing something blindingly obvious wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried..."'--register-pepper-plugins="path_to_plugin";mime_type'"?  That is double-quote followed by single-quote and the reverse at the end.  I seem to remember having to do that for running some Powershell code.

Answer (score 4):

Escaping quotes in arguments is a historical thing in vscode - see an explanation post near the bottom of [their issue discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98471).

Meanwhile, you can somewhat work around it if you use this (launch.json) configuration setting:

```
"console": "internalConsole",
```

as of today, vscode doesn't escape anything if running commands through that internal console. "externalTerminal" value also works. If using internal console, consider "internalConsoleOptions" choice to see what's happening in there.

Answer (score -8):

The way to do this is by using backlash to escape your extra quote, eg:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "exec",
        "remotePath": "",
        "port": 2345,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "program": "C:\\Geth\\gs\\bin\\geth.exe",
        "env": {},
        "args": ["--datadir",
             "/tmp/eth/60/01" ,
            "--verbosity",
            "9",
            "--nodiscover", 
            "--bootnodes",
            "enode://c50f8c5a50b898ab66231754855c582548ce722311e73c5e664a563ff35d8bddb26c10c74c2ebe62c69c6c7ed00031ef3e2d7fd563ff77cff91775cd3f07e4c3@[::]:30301",  
            "--ipcdisable",
            "--port",
            "30303", 
            "--rpcport",
            "8101",
            "console 2"],
        "showLog": true
    }
]
```

}

Comment: A really terrible answer. Your example has no escaped quotes and not even runtimeArgs. Besides, the question clearly shows that the OP has tried normal escaping.

Comment: I wonder if you even tried it... because adding a backslash doesn't work.